# Renaming multiples files to delete _number_ portion using bash in the Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I have a sequence of files

```
loading_0001_2.png,
loading_0002_3.png,
loading_0003_4.png,
...
```

I want to strip the *number* from the filename using terminal command line.

So that the result becomes `loading_2.png`, `loading_3.png`, etc…

How can I do this? what command do I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, you can use parameter expansion:

```
for file in loading_*.png ; do
    mv "$file" loading_"${file##*_}"
done
```

`##` means *remove the longest matching pattern from the beginning*.